# Chosen-sprite.png with Wepacker on Rails 6 fails to compile : SassError: Invalid UTF-8 sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-chosen, webpacker

> I am leaving the question as is but please note that I have moved
>   forward with Select2 and have everything working with the same webpacker
>   config

I am trying to use the chosen-js lib from webpacker.  Webpack does not compile and Rails provides with the following error:

```
SassError: Invalid UTF-8 sequence
    on line 1 of node_modules/chosen-js/chosen-sprite.png
    from line 13 of app/javascript/init/index.css.scss
    from line 3 of  app/javascript/packs/stylesheets.css.scss
>> �PNG
^
@ ./app/javascript/packs/stylesheets.css.scss 1:14-220
```

My environment is configured as follows:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const erb =  require('./loaders/erb')

const webpack = require('webpack');
// Add an additional plugin of your choosing : ProvidePlugin
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'], // for Bootstrap 4
        toastr: 'toastr/toastr'
    })
)

environment.loaders.prepend('erb', erb);
```

I have deleted the webpack.config that I thought I needed to make chosen-js work and especially load images from the node packages.

Which I import as follows to allow for a multiple select into a rails app (acts-as_taggable_on).

app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")
require("jquery")
require("toastr")
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

// import bootstrap and custom sass files
import "./stylesheets.scss";

//import node lib
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'
import bootstrapSelect from 'bootstrap-select';

// for stimulus
import "controllers"
// other js libraries
import "../init/index.js";

const importAll = (r) => r.keys().map(r)
require.context('../images', true, /\.(gif|jpg|png|svg)$/i)
```

then in the init library, I import the file chosen.js which contains javascript is as follows:

```
import 'chosen-js/chosen.jquery'
import 'chosen-js'

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  $("#company_tag_ids").chosen(
    {
      multiple: true,
      allow_single_deselect: true,
      width: '100%',
      placeholder_text_multiple: "Which are two of most productive days     of your week",
      no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"}
  )
})
```

The form is the following:

```
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox chosen-select">
         <%= f.collection_select(:tag_ids, ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.order(:name), :id, :name, { multiple: true, class:         'chosen-select' }) do |b| %>
         <% end %>
      </div>
```

Chosen-js works but I cannot get to a form with multi select like the tag_list field in stack over flow.  Especially when I try to use the spring-chosen.png, to style it bootstrap way, I receive a missing file error.

Not that I "solved" the missing file error but updating the web pack.config file as initially shown with an url-loader.

Comment: What's in app/javascript/init/index.css.scss? That's in the stacktrace.

Comment: I m importing @import‘chosen.js/../chosen.css‘ together with the chosen-sprite.png  in init together with the rest of the node css lib. Then i import the init/index.css.scss into javascript/packs/stylesheets.css

Comment: Please add that info to your question^^ so it is more readable

Comment: Also, I don't understand how you're using Webpacker with your given Webpack config as it doesn't seem to follow the guidelines in the rails/webpacker docs. It looks like you're using your own config with Webpack? How are you tying it to Rails then?

Comment: all updated to show how I have setup webpacker.  I do not normally use a custom webpack.config file  I only tried to make chosen-js work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `example/chosen` branch of my Rails 6 Webpacker demo project. It provides a working demonstration of using Webpack to bundle chosen-js, along with jQuery, to enhance a United States select menu.

https://github.com/rossta/rails6-webpacker-demo/tree/example/chosen

A few recommendations:

- Import the chosen css right from your JavaScript. It's not Sass so you may as well co-locate the import with your usage in JS:

  ```
  import $ from 'jquery'

  import 'chosen-js/chosen.css'
  import 'chosen-js'

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    $(".js-source-states").chosen()
  })
  ```
- You can use the imports-loader to get chosen-js to work with your yarn-installed jquery instance. See https://github.com/rossta/rails6-webpacker-demo/commit/7ee819506d9b60cd296eb36fc8e9414d1e5b377e